# NodeJS and MongoDB: Is there a way to listen to a collection and have an callback be called when a collection has new document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

Is there a way to listen to a MongoDB collection and have a callback gets triggered when a collection has a new document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there isn't a way yet. There is a lot of discussion in the "triggers" JIRA about related topics:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124

You can work around this by polling with timestamps or counts, but an event callback would obviously be better.

Comment: Ugh that sux. So my only way is to actually do an insert thru node right. Cause when i do insert, i can pass in a callback that will be called when insert returns?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but that's one way to have a sort of callback. Can you give more details?

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any active pushes from the DB, but you could hook into replication.

Let's assume you have a [replica set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets) (you wouldn't run single mongod, would you?).

Every change is written to the [oplog](http://ru.wiki.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets+-+Oplog) on the primary and then is replicated to secondaries.

You can efficiently pull new changes (both inserts and updates) from the oplog, using [tailable cursors](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors). Note, this is still pull, not push.